# How can I make two columns with a RecylcerView?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-recyclerview

I'm new to the Android Programming.
I created a soundboard, which looks like this:
 https://gyazo.com/2a08bcd731fb1cfeb07e72f75bc05e7e

But I dont understand how I can do this with a `RecyclerView`.
Here is the code with 2 columns and only 3 rows (normaly there are 200 rows):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="Button1"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"                       
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="Button2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button2"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button3"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="Button3"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button3"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button4"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="Button3"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button4"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button5"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="Button5"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button5"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button6"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="Button6"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button6"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

    </GridLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

How can I do this with a `RecyclerView` and an adapter? I read a lot tutorials, but I don't get it. How can I make 2 columns? Is there a good tutorial which explains this case?
Or can someone explain it to me?
The sounds are not taken out of a Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With RecyclerView the elements of the view are laid out according to the LayoutManager that you connect to your RecyclerView instance. If you would like the elements to be laid out in a 2 column grid, you can use the [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)

Per the documentation, you can create a new GridLayoutManager with **`N`** columns by using the constructor: `new GridLayoutManager(context,`**`N`**`);`